# Can't create ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just followed every step for installing ruby on rails as it says here http://rubyonrails.org/download but i can't create succesfully a rails project. This is exactly what I did:

1. Installed ruby with windows installer v2.0.0-p0 x64 (I'm running W8 pro)
2. Installed RubyGems with the following procedure:

   1. Downloaded thee .zip file from the webpage
   2. Unzipped the folder into the Ruby200-x64 folder in C:
   3. Excecuted the "setup.rb" file
3. Installed Rails with the following procedure:

   1. Opened a CMD and put `gem install rails`

But when I try to "create the application skeleton" through the command

```
rails new C:\Users\Andrés\Desktop\Mediplan
```

I get the following:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/generators/app_base-rb:100:in 'expand_path' : incompatible character encodings: CP850 and UTF-8 <Encoding::CompatibilityError>
```

Anybody knows a fix for this?
(Let me know if additional information is needed)

Comment: if your using unix go have a look at rvm https://rvm.io/. Should make your install a little easier.

Comment: Typically in `rails new` you just specify the name of the application, not the full path, and it will create the application in the working directory. Does `rails new Mediplan` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be due to the `é` in `Andrés`. Try changing your path to the `Desktop` first, then create the Rails app. Try this:

```
cd C:\Users\Andrés\Desktop
rails new Mediplan
```

Comment: Sounds correct if it raises the error: `incompatible character encodings: CP850 and UTF-8 <Encoding::CompatibilityError>`. I'm guessing a Windows encoding 'CP850' isn't friends with UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you, It finally tried to create the project (in fact there is now the folder in the desktop), but then it had an error in the cmd: at `run bundle install` it showed:

`C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/net/http.rb:917:in 'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed <OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError>`

Comment: Hmm, not so sure about that. Sorry. Try opening a new SO issue.